# Input Validation in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, textbox

Don't want the error message to be displayed at start/as tab opens.

Validation is implemented using IDataErrorInfo (to VM), an ErrorTemplate (XAML) is defined and able to get error message beside TextBox.

```cs
VM:(extended IDataErrorInfo)
public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string validationResult = null;
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                case "ProjectManager":
                validationResult = ValidateManagerName();
                break;
                }
                return validationResult;
            }
        }
        public string ValidateManagerName()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ProjectManager))
            {
                return "Manager name is mandatory!";
            }
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
```

```
XAML.cs
save_option_summ()
{
  BindingExpression be3 = managername.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            be3.UpdateSource();
}
```

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Foreground="Blue" FontSize="13" Text="{Binding ElementName=adorned,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" >
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2">
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adorned"/>
                    </Border>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <Label Content="Project Manager" FontSize="14" Margin="100,0,0,0" Width="150" FontFamily="Calibri"></Label>
            <TextBox  Height="auto" Width="300" Background="White"  Margin="100,0,0,0" Validation.ErrorTemplate = "{StaticResource ResourceKey=ErrorTemplate}" Name="managername" Text="{Binding ProjectManager,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" TextChanged="TextChanged"  FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="14"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the TextBox style so it shows what's wrong with the property. Here is a simple example that shows the error as tooltip:

```
 <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors).[0].ErrorContent}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This helped me to display error message in tooltip. Actually I was returning error message when textbox is empty. Hence always it was showing red around TextBox. Now returning 'string.empty'.

Comment: Glad it helped please mark it correct answer if it resolved ur issue

Answer (score 0):

So, along with shivam sood's (which helps to show error in tooltip) answer.

In code shown above (question),

```
public string ValidateManagerName()
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ProjectManager))
        {
            return "string.Empty";
        }
        //Other conditions can be written like alphanumeric check
        else
            return string.Empty;
 }
```

Don't return anything in null check (first condition), so that textbox will not always show error message.